# Variable substitution in Makefile yields unexpected results

Tags: makefile

I have a Makefile:

```
FOO=one two

$(FOO):
    echo $@
```

Now I run:

`make one` and get `echo one`

`make two` and get `echo two`

`make three` and get an error

This is expected.

However, when I change the Makefile to:

```
FOO=one two

$(FOO)$(FOO):
    echo $@
```

It is still the same!

I would expect that I have to type `make oneone`, but this is not the case.

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `make` trustfully pastes whatever you give it as contents. Depending on the invisible rest of the line in `FOO=one two...` i.e. if you have a space there or not, you are producing `one twoone two` or `one two one two`. The latter is, I think, not illegal but will produce a warning like `target given more than once in same line`.